# How to config TODO patterns on Netbeans 8?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I am used to work with TODO comments on my code, and it was never a problem on Eclipse or Netbeans, but in Netbeans 8, I can't find my way into Action Items configuration.

I think it was on Tools > Options > Miscellaneous, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can see the TODO config in:

Tools → Options → Team → Action Items

**Screenshot:**

[image]